# how I can retain the saved data when I switch pages

Tags: java, javafx

I success make my page is work but when I go to another page and I go back all of data restarted.

And why it's happen? what must I do?

I make my date save in array and object

I save my data in Produk class and I make the object named produkAdded, and the kategori on an array

```
package com.finalalp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.ContextMenuEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

public class ListProdukScreen implements Initializable {
    public Kategori daftarKategori = new Kategori(null);

    // List produk
    @FXML
    void switchToHomeScreen(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        App.setRoot("homeScreen");
    }

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> addListKategori;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> listKategori;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> listPilihKategori;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Produk> tableListProduk;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Produk, String> deskripsi;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Produk, Number> harga;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Produk, String> nama;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Produk, String> kategoriTable;

    @FXML
    private TextField namaKategoriBaru;

    @FXML
    private TextField namaProduk;
    @FXML
    private TextField deskripsiProduk;
    @FXML
    private TextField hargaProduk;

    @FXML
    private TextField searchBarProduk;

    ScrollPane scrollPane = ScrollPane();

    @FXML
    void tambahkanProduk(ActionEvent event) {

        Produk produkAdded = new Produk(namaProduk.getText(), deskripsiProduk.getText(), listPilihKategori.getValue(),
                Integer.parseInt(hargaProduk.getText()));
        produkAdded.setHarga(Integer.parseInt(hargaProduk.getText()));
        produkAdded.setNama(namaProduk.getText());
        produkAdded.setKategori(listPilihKategori.getValue());
        produkAdded.setDeskripsi(deskripsiProduk.getText());
        datalist.addAll(produkAdded);
        tableListProduk.getItems().add(produkAdded);
        namaProduk.clear();
        deskripsiProduk.clear();
        hargaProduk.clear();
    }

    private ScrollPane ScrollPane() {

        return null;
    }

    @FXML
    void pilihListKategori(MouseEvent event) {

        searchBarProduk.setText(listKategori.getValue());
    }

    ObservableList<Produk> datalist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    void filterPencarian(MouseEvent event) {

        // Searchbarnya cuuuy T_T
        FilteredList<Produk> filteredListdata = new FilteredList<>(datalist, b -> true);
        searchBarProduk.textProperty().addListener((Observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredListdata.setPredicate(Produk -> {
                if (newValue.isBlank() || newValue.isEmpty() || newValue == null) {
                    return true;
                }
                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
                if (Produk.getKategori().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                    return true;
                } else if (Produk.getNama().toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) != -1) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });

        SortedList<Produk> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredListdata);

        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableListProduk.comparatorProperty());

        tableListProduk.setItems(sortedData);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        addListKategori.getItems().addAll(daftarKategori.makanan);

        nama.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Produk, String>("nama"));
        harga.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Produk, Number>("harga"));
        deskripsi.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Produk, String>("deskripsi"));
        kategoriTable.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Produk, String>("kategori"));

    }

    public void submitKategoriBaru(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        String namaKategoString = addListKategori.getValue();
        switch (namaKategoString) {
            case "1. Nama kategori":
                addListKategori.getItems().remove(namaKategoString);
                daftarKategori.makanan[0] = "1. " + namaKategoriBaru.getText();
                addListKategori.getItems().add(0, daftarKategori.makanan[0]);
                listKategori.getItems().add(0, daftarKategori.makanan[0]);
                listPilihKategori.getItems().add(0, daftarKategori.makanan[0]);

                // root = loader.load();
                break;

            case "2. Nama kategori":
                addListKategori.getItems().remove(namaKategoString);
                daftarKategori.makanan[1] = "2. " + namaKategoriBaru.getText();
                addListKategori.getItems().add(1, daftarKategori.makanan[1]);
                listKategori.getItems().add(1, daftarKategori.makanan[1]);
                listPilihKategori.getItems().add(1, daftarKategori.makanan[1]);

                break;

            case "3. Nama kategori":
                addListKategori.getItems().remove(namaKategoString);
                daftarKategori.makanan[2] = "3. " + namaKategoriBaru.getText();
                addListKategori.getItems().add(2, daftarKategori.makanan[2]);
                listKategori.getItems().add(2, daftarKategori.makanan[2]);
                listPilihKategori.getItems().add(2, daftarKategori.makanan[2]);

                break;

            case "4. Nama kategori":
                addListKategori.getItems().remove(namaKategoString);
                daftarKategori.makanan[3] = "4. " + namaKategoriBaru.getText();
                addListKategori.getItems().add(3, daftarKategori.makanan[3]);
                listKategori.getItems().add(3, daftarKategori.makanan[3]);
                listPilihKategori.getItems().add(3, daftarKategori.makanan[3]);

                break;

            case "5. Nama kategori":
                addListKategori.getItems().remove(namaKategoString);
                daftarKategori.makanan[4] = "5. " + namaKategoriBaru.getText();
                addListKategori.getItems().add(4, daftarKategori.makanan[4]);
                listKategori.getItems().add(4, daftarKategori.makanan[4]);
                listPilihKategori.getItems().add(4, daftarKategori.makanan[4]);

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < daftarKategori.makanan.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(daftarKategori.makanan[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

I am trying to make my code when it's running although I go to another page still the data save.

I make the data save with Array and Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have saved all your data inside a controller class instance which is probably recreated and all data is lost when you switch pages. You have to store your persistent data outside of your controllers.